# Output Keystrokes

Tags: code-golf, string, animation

In any programming language, create a program that takes input and animates the text being typed on a keyboard.

The delay between each character should be varying to simulate true typing on a keyboard. The delay shall be `0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5 ...` seconds, until the last character is printed. The final output shall be left on the screen.

You must overwrite the current line of text you can't have the text be printed on new rows.

Example, the input "Hello, PPCG! Goodbye Earth!" should result in the following animation (note that the sampling rate of the gif-maker was low, so the true result is slightly different):

[image]

Since this is code golf, the smallest amount of bytes win.

Comment: "You must overwrite the current line of text you can't have the text be printed on new rows." - is this implying that the program must clear the input and produce output in it's place? (Side note: your animation looks faster than specified.)

Comment: Can we assume there is always input?

Comment: And can we exit with an error after the animation is done?

Comment: Is the delay supposed to be random, or a repeating pattern of 0.1, 0.1, 0.5?

Comment: Should there be a delay before printing the first character?

Comment: It's that pattern yes @12Me21

Comment: I'm not sure if I can time stuff that accurately on the Commodore 64 (without a SuperCPU, I might be able to with) or Sinclair ZX81, would it be okay if I don't hit these timings on that basis?

Comment: I should have added Commodore and Sinclair ZX81 BASIC - assembly would be a different beast

Answer (score 8):

### C <s>108</s> <s>93</s> <s>89</s> <s>78</s> <s>73</s> 80 bytes

```
f(char *s){for(int i=0;s[i];fflush(0),usleep(100000*(i++%3?1:5)))putchar(s[i]);}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
 void f(char *s)
 {
  for( int i=0;s[i];)
  {
    putchar(s[i]);
    fflush(0);
    usleep(100000*(i++%3?1:5));
 }
}
```

@Kritixi Lithos  @Metoniem Thanks for your input! saved some bytes.

Somehow, just `int i` gave me a segmentation error on running, so I initialized it with 0.

Comment: Wether you use my improvements or not: Your delays should be the other way around. if `i%3` the delay should be 5.

Comment: Replace `100000` with `1e5` to shave 3 bytes

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Thanks for the tip, updated. I have used it in some of my other solutions too don't know why I forgot here.

Comment: @AbelTom For some reason, `1e5` doesn't work on my device

Comment: @KritixiLithos howcome? are you on Linux?

Comment: @AbelTom No, I'm on macOS

Comment: @KritixiLithos According to `man usleep`, the function takes unsigned int as argument, I don't even get a warning. May be compiler does the typecasting implicitly.

Comment: C only default-initialises global variables to 0, not local variables.

Comment: @Neil Thanks, did not know that, learnt something new, :) updated!

Comment: I think this is 72 bytes not 73

Comment: Also you can get down to 68 bytes by moving the putchar into your for-loop's conditional section. Will return false if there is nothing to putchar. `i;f(char *s){for(;putchar(s[i]);fflush(0),usleep(1e5*(i++%3?5:1)));}` Note: I could not find an online C IDe that supported usleep in the output so I wasn't able to test this and see if it works in terms of the animation, but the logic part of it did work.

Comment: **1.** The delays are wrong. `i++%3?5:1` will return **5** twice and **1** once. It should be backwards. **2.** Without including `unistd.h`, the compiler cannot possibly know that `usleep` expects an int, so it will pass a float. There is no conversion there; the byte representation of **1e5** gets used as is. **3.** Per meta consensus, functions have to be reusable, so you have to reset your counter to **0**.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for the feedback! **1.** I was right the first time I implemented the delay with `if` `else`. **2.** I have `unistd.h` included, so that explains the type conversion of 1e5.If one does not have it included, then the representation should be in `int` format. **3.**  Re-wrote the code such that `i` is local and initialized to 0.

Comment: The sleep times still don't seem quite right, as it should sleep 0.1 seconds after the first character, 0.5 seconds after the third. This works and it's a bit shorter. `i;f(char*s){for(i=0;putchar(*s++);usleep(100000*(++i%3?1:5)))fflush();}` It prints a null byte at the end, but since this challenge is about visual output, I think that's OK.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
115D÷⁵ṁȮœS¥@"
```

This is a monadic link/function. Due to implicit output, it doesn't work as a full program.

#### Verification

[image]

#### How it works

```
115D÷⁵ṁȮœS¥@"  Monadic link. Argument: s (string)

115            Set the return value to 115.
   D           Decimal; yield [1, 1, 5].
    ÷⁵         Divide all three integers by 10.
      ṁ        Mold; repeat the items of [0.1, 0.1, 0.5] as many times as
               necessary to match the length of s.
          ¥@"  Combine the two links to the left into a dyadic chain and apply it
               to each element in s and the corr. element of the last return value.
       Ȯ         Print the left argument of the chain (a character of s) and sleep
                 as many seconds as the right argument indicates (0.1 or 0.5).
```

Answer (score 6):

## MATLAB, 74 bytes

```
c=input('');p=[1,1,5]/10;for i=c;fprintf('%s',i);p=p([2,3,1]);pause(p);end
```

#### Explanation:

I used quite a while to make the `fprintf` version shorter than `disp()` with `clc`. The breakthrough was when I found out / remembered that `pause` can take a vector as argument, in which case it will just pick the first value. This makes it possible to leave out a counter.

```
c=input('');    % Take input as 'Hello'
p=[.1,.1,.5];   % The various pause times

for i=c;            % For each of the characters in the input c
  fprintf('%s',i);  % Print the character i, without any trailing newline or whitespace
                    % No need to clear the screen, it will just append the new character 
                    % after the existing ones
  pause(p);         % pause for p(1) seconds. If the input to pause is a vector, 
                    % then it will choose the first value
  p=p([2,3,1]);     % Shift the pause times
end
```

The shortest I got using `disp` was 81 bytes:

```
c=input('');p=[1,1,5]/10;for i=1:nnz(c),clc;disp(c(1:i));pause(p(mod(i,3)+1));end
```

Comment: Can  you do `printf` instead of `fprintf`? It works on https://octave-online.net/ (but it's Octave and not Matlab)

Answer (score 4):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/), <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @DJMcMayhem*

*saved 1 byte by removing `ò` at the end*

```
òD1gÓulD1gÓulDgÓul
```

Terribly ungolfy, I know, it's just that strict `u`ndo preventing me to use nested loops.

#### Explanation

The cursor starts in the beginning of the buffer, which is the first character of the input.

```
ò                      " Start recursion
 D                     " Deletes everything from the cursor's position to the end of line
  1gÓ                  " Sleep for 100ms
     u                 " Undo (now the deletion is reverted)
      l                " Move cursor one to the right
       D1gÓul          " Do it again
             D         " Same as before but...
              gÓ       " Sleep for 500ms this time
                ul     " Then undo and move right
                       " Implicit ò
```

Gif coming soon...

Comment: `gÓ` without a count defaults to 500 ms, so you can save a byte there. Also, remember that you don't need the second `ò`!

Comment: Instead of `u`ndo can you just `p`aste?  Unsure if that helps at all though

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I don't know why I missed the default 500, thanks! But I need the second `ò` because otherwise the program terminates early on account of the implicit newline at the end causing a breaking error.

Comment: @nmjcman101 I was also thinking about using `p`aste, but alas it moves the cursor to the end of the line and to go back I would need something like `\`\`` which would only increase my bytecount further

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 67 bytes

```js
f=(i,o,n=0)=>i[n]&&(o.data+=i[n],setTimeout(f,++n%3?100:500,i,o,n))
```

```html
<form><input id=i><button onclick=f(i.value,o.firstChild)>Go!</button><pre id=o>
```

Comment: The snippet doesn't seem to work

Comment: @KritixiLithos Yup, doesn't seem to work on Chrome :-(

Comment: works in firefox tho

Comment: It works for me in Chrome, but the console says `Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.`

Comment: @numbermaniac I changed the snippet to use a different event. (I'm so old I can actually remember when hitting Enter in a form field didn't trigger the following button but went straight to form submission.)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 16 bytes

```
"@&htDTT5hX@)&Xx
```

[Try it at MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=%22%40%26htDTT5hX%40%29%26Xx&inputs=%27Hello%2C+PPCG%21+Goodbye+Earth%21%27&version=19.8.0)

#### Explanation

```
"        % Implicitly input string. For each char of it
  @      %   Push current char
  &h     %   Concatenate everything so far into a string
  tD     %   Duplicate and display
  TT5h   %   Push array [1 1 5]
  X@)    %   Get the k-th element modularly, where k is current iteration.
         %   So this gives 1, 1, 5 cyclically
  &Xx    %   Pause for that many tenths of a second and clear screen
         % Implicit end. Implicitly display the final string, again (screen
         % was deleted at the end of the last iteration)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Noodel](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/), 18 [bytes](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/docs/code_page.html)

```
ʋ115ṡḶƙÞṡạḌ100.ṡ€ß
```

[Try it:)](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/editor.html?code=%CA%8B115%E1%B9%A1%E1%B8%B6%C6%99%C3%9E%E1%B9%A1%E1%BA%A1%E1%B8%8C100.%E1%B9%A1%E2%82%AC%C3%9F&input=%22Hello%2C%20PPCG!%20Goodbye%20Earth!%22&run=false)

---

#### How it works

```
                   # Input is automatically pushed to the stack.
ʋ                  # Vectorize the string into an array of characters.
 115               # Push on the string literal "115" to be used to create the delays.
    ṡ              # Swap the two items on the stack.

     ḶƙÞṡạḌ100.ṡ€  # The main loop for the animation.
     Ḷ             # Loops the following code based off of the length of the string.
      ƙ            # Push on the current iteration's element of the character array (essentially a foreach).
       Þ           # Pop off of the stack and push to the screen.
        ṡ          # Swap the string "115" and he array of characters (this is done because need array of characters on the top for the loop to know how many times to loop)
         ạ         # Grab the next character in the string "115" (essentially a natural animation cmd that every time called on the same object will access the next item looping)
                   # Also, turns the string into an array of characters.
          Ḍ100.    # Pop the character off and convert to a number then multiply by 100 to get the correct delay. Then delay for that many ms.
               ṡ   # Swap the items again to compensate for the one earlier.
                €  # The end of the loop.

                 ß # Clears the screen such that when implicit popping of the stack occurs it will display the correct output.
```

---

**19 byte** code snippet that loops endlessly.

```html
<div id="noodel" cols="30" rows="2" code="ʋ115ṡḷḶƙÞṡạḌ100.ṡ€ß" input='"Hello, PPCG! Goodbye Earth!"'/>
<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/release/noodel-2.5.js"></script>
<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/ppcg.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For some reason, the delay seems off. The delay is 100ms, 100ms, 500ms. You seem to have 100ms all the time.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Good eye. After looking through the source there is an add instead of a multiply. I might keep it that way though in case I need that because I could see where it might be useful. Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: You're welcome. And I'm sorry that your byte count increased.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, it's fine because when I make the next version of _Noodel_ I can make an __11 byte__ solution (because of basics I need to add). It will obviously be noncompeting, but this is a new language and has a long ways to go before it is as good as some of the top golfing languages:)

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <s>131</s> bytes

Not much to explain. It just takes a string (wrapped in "") as argument and prints each character using the correct delay pattern. After the animation it exits with an `OutOfRangeException` because the loop doesn't stop after it looped over all characters. Since it's an infinite loop, that also means I can use `int Main` instead of `void Main` ;-)

### Golfed

```
class C{static int Main(string[]a){for(int i=0;){System.Console.Write(a[0][i]);System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(i++%3<1?500:100);}}}
```

## Ungolfed

```
class C
{
    static int Main(string[] a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; ;)
        {
            System.Console.Write(a[0][i]);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(i++ % 3 < 1 ? 500 : 100);
        }
    }
}
```

### Edits

- Saved 1 byte by moving incrementing `i` inside of the `Sleep()` method instead of in the `for` loop. (Thanks [Maliafo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56032/maliafo))

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer, but can't you do something like `Sleep(i++ [...])` to save an extra byte in the for loop ?

Comment: @Maliafo You might be right! I'll run it to make sure if it still runs correctly and then update my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 23 bytes

```
⊢{⍞←⍺⊣⎕DL⍵÷10}¨1 1 5⍴⍨⍴
```

Explanation:

```
               1 1 5⍴⍨⍴  ⍝ repeat the values [1,1,5] to match the input length
⊢                        ⍝ the input itself
 {           }¨          ⍝ pairwise map
      ⎕DL⍵÷10            ⍝ wait ⍵÷10 seconds, where ⍵ is the number
     ⊣                   ⍝ ignore that value, and
  ⍞←⍺                    ⍝ output the character
```

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 61 bytes

```
LINPUT S$FOR I=0TO LEN(S$)-1?S$[I];
WAIT 6+24*(I MOD 3>1)NEXT
```

I think the delay calculation could be a lot shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>83</s> 75 bytes

```python
import time;i=0
for c in input():i+=1;print(end=c);time.sleep(i%3and.1or.5)
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/Fqlc/0)

Comment: This doesn't work on TIO. Do it [here](https://repl.it/languages/Python3). On repl.it, you don't even need `,flush=1`.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 81 bytes

```clj
#(doseq[[c d](map vector %(cycle[100 100 500]))](Thread/sleep d)(print c)(flush))
```

Loops over the input string zipped with a infinite list of `[100 100 500]`.

```clj
(defn typer [input]
  ; (map vector... is generally how you zip lists in Clojure 
  (doseq [[chr delay] (map vector input (cycle [100 100 500]))]
    (Thread/sleep delay)
    (print chr) (flush)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bash (+utilities), 32 byte

> Note, this will beep in the process, but who said submissions can not have fancy sound effects !

**Golfed**

```
sed 's/.../&\a\a\a\a/g'|pv -qL10
```

**Demo**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, <s>66</s> <s>65</s> 63 Bytes

```
[char[]]$args|%{sleep -m((1,1,5)[++$i%3]*100);Write-Host $_ -N}
```

[image]

-1 removed unneeded white space after `-m`

-2 thanks to AdmBorkBork - used `1,1,5` and `*` end result by `100` instead of using `100,100,500`

takes `$args` as a char array, loops through sleeping as specified, `Write-Host` with the `-N`oNewline argument is used to write the chars out on the same line.

Improvements?

- use `[0..99]` instead of `[char[]]` to save 1 byte, but wont work on strings over 100 chars.
- use `100,500` and `[(++$i%3)-gt1]` but make it shorter somehow.
- combine it into a single string and clear between outputs, eliminating the long `Write-Host`

can't find any way to make the last two work, and the first one isn't valid by any particular rule.

Comment: Break out the hundred to save two bytes -- `sleep -m((1,1,5)[++$i%3]*100)`

Comment: @AdmBorkBork smart one - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Processing, <s>133</s> 131 bytes

```processing
int i;void setup(){for(String c:String.join("",args).split(""))p{try{Thread.sleep(i++%3<1?500:100);}catch(Exception e){}print(c);}}
```

*I tried doing `args[0]` and wrapping the argument in `""` instead, but it does not work for some reason.*

Anyways... this is the first time I've written a Processing program that takes arguments. Unlike Java, you don't need to declare the arguments using `String[]args`, but the variable `args` will automatically be initialised to the arguments.

Put it in a file called `sketch_name.pde` under a folder called `sketch_name` (yes, same name for folder and sketch).  Call it like:

```processing
processing-java --sketch=/full/path/to/sketch/folder --run input text here
```

[image: cheese]

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 63 bytes

```perl
foreach(split//,pop){$|=++$i;print;select('','','',$i%3?.1:.5)}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 88 Bytes

```py
import time;s=''
for x in input():s+=x;time.sleep(.1+.4*(len(s)%3==0));print('\n'*25+s)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Rebol, 65 bytes

```
s: input t:[.1 .1 .5]forall s[prin s/1 wait last append t take t]
```

Ungolfed:

```
s: input
t: [.1 .1 .5]

forall s [
    prin s/1
    wait last append t take t
]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash + coreutils, 57 bytes

```
for((;k<${#1};k++)){ echo -n ${1:k:1};sleep .$[2&k%3|1];}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, <s>151</s> 149 bytes

```
class M{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{int n=0;for(String c:a[0].split("")){System.out.print(c);Thread.sleep(n++%3>0?100:500);}}}
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@KritixiLithos* for something I always forget..

**Explanation:**

```
class M{
  public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception{ // throws Exception is required due to the Thread.sleep
    int n = 0;                                          // Initialize counter (and set to 0)
    for(String c : a[0].split("")){                     // Loop over the characters of the input
      System.out.print(c);                              // Print the character
      Thread.sleep(n++ % 3 > 0 ?                        // if (n modulo 3 != 0)
                                 100                    //   Use 100 ms
                               :                        // else (n modulo 3 == 0):
                                 500);                  //   Use 500 ms
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
java -jar M.jar "Hello, PPCG! Goodbye Earth!"
```

Comment: I haven't tested it, but can you do something like `a[0].split("")` instead?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Argg.. I always forget that one. Thanks.

Comment: Speaking about which, I should also use `split` in my Processing answer...